# Replace double quotes with single quotes between pairs of square brackets

Tags: python-3.x, regex, string

```
a = """abcda"sd"asd["first", "last", "middle", "dob", "gender"]abcda"sd"asd"""
a = re.sub("\[(\".*?\",?)*\]", r'\g<0>'.replace('"', ""), a)
print(a)
```

I am trying to replace the  double qoutations in the provided string.
Is the method i am using correct?

Is there another method (one-liner preferred) to obtain the desired result.

Desired string result as below

```
"""abcda"sd"asd['first', 'last', 'middle', 'dob', 'gender']abcda"sd"asd"""
```

I need to replace double quotes only inside the square brackets `[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can omit the capture group from the pattern as you are replacing on the whole match.

The pattern `\[(\".*?\",?)*\]` can also match a `,` at the end, and uses a non greedy match between the double quotes.

What you might do is use a negated character class `[^"]*` instead to match all between the double quotes, and optionally repeat a non capture group`(?:\s*,\s*"[^"]*")*` with a leading comma to not allow a comma at the end.

re.sub can use a lambda where you might also do the replacement of the double quotes.

```
import re

a = """abcda"sd"asd["first", "last", "middle", "dob", "gender"]"""
a = re.sub(r'\["[^"]*"(?:\s*,\s*"[^"]*")*', lambda m: m.group().replace('"', "'"), a)
print(a)
```

Output

```
abcda"sd"asd['first', 'last', 'middle', 'dob', 'gender']
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the newer `regex` module and `\G` as in:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)[^"\]\[]*|\[)\K"
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/GkU88f/1).

---

In terms of `Python` this could be

```
import regex as re

text = """abcda"sd"asd["first", "last", "middle", "dob", "gender"]abcda"sd"asd"""
pattern = re.compile(r'''(?:\G(?!\A)[^"\]\[]*|\[)\K"''')

text = pattern.sub("'", text)

print(text)
```

And would yield

```
abcda"sd"asd['first', 'last', 'middle', 'dob', 'gender']abcda"sd"asd
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method replace.
`a.replace('"', "'")`

Comment: i want to replace qoutes only inside the []